# Give an example of $a$ interval $[a,b]$ and two integrable function $f$ and $g$ such that $U(f+g,P)<U(f,P)+U(g,P)$

Tags: real-analysis

Initially I wasn't sure if this was possible, then I started thinking of functions that are below 0 or negative. So lets say $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ and the interval $[1,2]$. It is obviously true that the supremum of $f(x)$ in this interval is $x=2 , f(x)=2$, but for $g(x)=-$x, I believe the supremum for this interval is $x=1 g(x)=-1$ right? The reason I am assuming that is because it is the less negative value.

Comment: What is $P\mbox{}$?

Comment: a partition of the interval

Comment: and what is $U$?

Comment: I meant, in the example you provided what was the partition $P$?

Comment: @Targon this is very standard notation for "upper sum".

Comment: so is the example I've provided correct?

Comment: The example is correct. You get $U(g,P)=-1$ for the simple partition with one subinterval $[1,2]$ because $-1 \geqslant g(x) \geqslant -2$.

Comment: You will get $U(f+g,P) = 0 < 2+ -1 = U(f,P) + U(g,P)$.